# Is it possible to use type traits to check whether a type is a container?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Can I use C++ Type Traits to check if a type is an STL-like container? I already know of GCC's builtin `__is_class` but I would like to be a bit more specific if possible.

Comment: Define what "STL-like" means.

Comment: @JohnPS: A container needs `value_type`, `iterator`, `const_iterator`, `reference`, `const_reference`, `pointer`, `difference_type`, `size_type`, `begin()`, `end()`, `size()`, `max_size()`, `empty()`, and `swap()`, and must fulfill a few other straightforward conditions.

Comment: Dang, I guess `std::forward_list` isn't a container then (it doesn't have `size()`).  My point:  I'm not currently aware of a universally accepted definition of container.

Comment: Perhaps you could learn from the concept checks done in Boost Range Library - or simply use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build your own traits classes to check a type for the Container interface. This would involve validating that certain associated types (such as `container::iterator`) exist and validating that certain expressions (such as `container.empty()`) are valid (i.e., they compile without error). Various SFINAE techniques can be used to build traits classes which check for nested types and validate expressions.

SGI's [page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html) specifies in detail the associated types and valid expressions that types which model the Container "concept" must provide. The most recent ISO C++ standard document would probably provide a more authoritative source since the SGI page is pretty old.

Of course, traits classes can't validate the semantics of expressions like `container.empty()`; they can only check that the expressions are legal. Some have [proposed](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2887.pdf&ei=CneHTtWSD9PdiALqkf2gDA&usg=AFQjCNEK0Ms1mEurE3hzgMy3FxomVUDVdQ&sig2=t7unKCxT2iKRJFuy1PgRnw) extending the language to allow the programmer to assert the semantic properties of expressions, which would address this limitation.

Comment: Excellent answer with some useful links. Thanks. See also the Boost traits documentation at http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html.