# C++ how to differentiate between template for container and native type

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following problem:

```
template<class T>
void set(std::string path, const T data)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << data << std::endl;
   write(path, ss.str();
}

template<class T>
void set(std::string path, const T data)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(typename T::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it < data.end(); ++it)
    {
       ss << *it;
       if(it < data.end() -1 )
          ss << ", ";
    }
    ss << std::endl;
    write(path, ss.str());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: ‘template<class T> void myclass::set(std::string, T)’ cannot be overloaded
error: with ‘template<class T> void myclass::set(std::string, T)’
```

Is there a way to differentiate between container types and other types in templates?

Comment: type traits. Looks like you need to make your own is_container trait (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617203/is-it-possible-to-use-type-traits-to-check-whether-a-type-is-a-container). (Haven't done this before, and just waiting for a build to complete, so not a complete answer - sorry. But I would be interested in the solution ;))

Comment: Do you want `const T & data`, and `ss << data`??

Comment: This is *almost* a great question, but there's a few syntax errors that made answering it harder than it needed to be. (`T` should be `data` on the third line of the first form of `set` and your calls to `write` are missing a `)` but still wrong after adding that).

Comment: Note that `it < data.end() - 1` requires not just that `T` is a container, but that it is a container with a random-access iterator. So for standard containers that's just `vector`, `deque` and in C++11 `array`, plus the various string classes could work in that template too. Also it's required that `data` is non-empty, which you certainly can't overload on ;-p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++03 you can do this with a little bit of SFINAE to selectively enable different versions of the function for different types:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void set(typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, std::string>::type path, const T data)
{
   std::cout << "POD" << std::endl;
   stringstream ss;
   ss << data << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void set(typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, std::string>::type path, const T data)
{
    std::cout << "Non-POD" << std::endl;
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(typename T::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it < data.end(); ++it)
    {
       ss << *it;
       if(it < data.end() -1 )
          ss << ", ";
    }
    ss << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int i;
  float f;
  std::vector<int> v;
  set("", v);
  set("", i);
  set("", f);
}
```

I used boost for convenience here, but you could roll your own if boost isn't an option or use C++11 instead.

`is_pod` isn't quite what you want really, you probably want an `is_container` trait, but [that's not so trivial, you'll need to make a trait of your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242209/is-container-trait-fails-on-stdset-sfinae-issue) and `is_pod` makes a good approximation for how to use traits to selectively enable functions as simple answer.

Answer (score 8):

Use a trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type
set (std::string const & path, T const & container)
{
    // for (auto const & x : container) // ...
}


template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_container<T>::value>::type
set (std::string const & path, T const & data)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << data;
    write(path, oss.str());
}
```

You can find a suitable trait in the [pretty printer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).

Answer (score 1):

You might try Substitution Failure Is Not An Error (SFINAE) techniques here.

Firstly, you need a function to determine whether a type has an iterator member...

```
template <typename T>
struct Has_Iterator
{
    template <typename>
    static char test(...);

    template <typename U>
    static int test(typename U::const_iterator*);

    static const bool result = sizeof test<T>(0) != sizeof(char);
};
```

In the above code, the C++ Standard requires `test(typename U::const_iterator*)` to be used in preference to the vague "..." parameter match, so long as `U` *is* actually a struct/class with a `const_iterator` member type.  Otherwise, you have a "substitution failure" - which is not a fatal error stopping compilation  (hence SFINAE), and the attempt to find a matching function is satified by `test(...)`.  As the return types of the two functions differ, the `sizeof` operator can test which one has been matched, setting the `result` boolean appropriately.

Then you can forward requests to print things to template specialisations that support them...

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& data)
{
    printer<Has_Iterator<T>::result, T>()(data);
}

// general case handles types having iterators...
template <bool Has_It, typename T>
struct printer
{
    void operator()(const T& data)
    {
        for (typename T::const_iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
            std::cout << *i << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

// specialisation for types lacking iterators...
template <typename T>
struct printer<false, T>
{
    void operator()(const T& data)
    {
        std::cout << data << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: Nitpick: *"the `sizeof` operator can test which one has been called"* -- `test()` is never really called at all.  You know this already, I'm sure.

Comment: @cdhowie: fair point - answer updated with "matched".  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As my predecessors wrote you have to use some kind of trait. You probably should use Boost for that, but if you don't want to you can just use something like this ( http://ideone.com/7mAiB ):

```
template <typename T>
struct has_const_iterator {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C> static yes& test(typename C::const_iterator*);
    template <typename> static no& test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <bool> class bool2class {};

template <class T>
void set_inner(const std::string &path, T & var, bool2class<false> *) {
        // T is probably not STL container
}

template <class T>
void set_inner(const std::string &path, T & var, bool2class<true> *) {
        // T is STL container
}

template <class T>
void set(const std::string &path, T &var) {
        set_inner(path, var, (bool2class<has_const_iterator<T>::value>*)0);
}
```

It's not an easy task to distinguish container from simple array, so I used here checking if type has `const_iterator`. Probably you should also check if it has `begin()`, `end()` and other things you would use in future code.