# How to write a streaming 'operator<<' that can take arbitary containers (of type 'X')?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iostream

I have a C++ class "`X`" which would have special meaning if ***a container*** of them were to be sent to a `std::ostream`.

I originally implemented it specifically for `std::vector<X>`:

```
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream &os, const std::vector<X> &c )
{
   // The specialized logic here expects c to be a "container" in simple
   // terms - only that c.begin() and c.end() return input iterators to X
}
```

If I wanted to support `std::ostream << std::deque<X>` or `std::ostream << std::set<X>` or any similar container type, the only solution I know of is to copy-paste the entire function and change only the function signature!

Is there a way to generically code `operator << ( std::ostream &, const Container & )`?

("`Container`" here would be any type that satisfies the commented description above.)

Comment: I would answer this with a template that just loops over the container printing each item in turn, however you wrote "The operation would be more complicated than just sending each X individually" which I think needs more explaination of what you actually want it to do?

Comment: Just overload `operator<<` for `Container` (is that really the type of the container class? Or is it more like `Container<T>`?). And there is no magic in C++ that will generate output for a container class if there is an output function for the items contained in the class.

Comment: I would be interested in an answer to @J99 's first question. Can you show us the implementation of `operator<<` for the vector case?

Comment: I apologise, actually when i look how I've one this in the code I was thinking ofI've had a separate template for "template <class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& data)" and another for list and so on.... So my comment is wrong - it won't let me edit my comment now,and deleting it would make these comments confusing...

Comment: Obviously that's not a general solution,and would likely not work with  allocators etc either.

Comment: A very simple solution would be to use `ostream << describe_range(your_container);` and have `describe_range` return either a `std::string` or overload on `operator<<(ostream&, range_description<Cont>)` or something similar.

Comment: There's actually a *rather* easy way of making the "overload on container of X" work, and I've basically finished it, but I'm still trying some things out and the explanation I saved in the answer draft vanished, so yeah... maybe sometime later tonight.

Comment: @Xeo I look forward to seeing that!  As you can see, it has stumped many.

Comment: @J99 Please go ahead and delete those comments.  I'll delete my matching ones.

Comment: If you don't mind a trivial one-line forwarding function per container, see my answer. A pragmatic solution, perhaps, and it does avoids most of the duplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have read this answer before, you might want to scroll down to the ADL version below.  It is much improved.

First, a short and sweet version that pretty much works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename Iterator, typename=void>
struct is_iterator_of_type: std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename Iterator>
struct is_iterator_of_type<
  T,
  Iterator,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      T,
      typename std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::value_type
    >::value
  >::type
>: std::true_type {};

template<typename Container>
auto operator<<( std::ostream& stream, Container const& c ) ->
  typename std::enable_if< is_iterator_of_type<int, typename Container::iterator>::value, std::ostream& >::type
{
  return stream << "int container\n";
}
template<typename Container>
auto operator<<( std::ostream& stream, Container const& c ) ->
  typename std::enable_if< is_iterator_of_type<double, typename Container::iterator>::value, std::ostream& >::type
{
  return stream << "double container\n";
}
```

which merely detects things that look sort of like `int` and `double` containers with distinct overloads.  I would advise changing the implementation of `operator<<`.  ;)

A more proper route (thanks @Xeo) would be this adl-hack.  We create an auxiliary namespace where we import `begin` and `end` from `std`, then some template functions that do argument dependent lookup on `begin` and `end` (seeing the `std` version if we don't have a more tightly bound one), and then use these `aux::adl_begin` functions to determine if what we are passed in can be treated as a container over X:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

template<typename T, typename Iterator, typename=void>
struct is_iterator_of_type: std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename Iterator>
struct is_iterator_of_type<
  T,
  Iterator,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      T,
      typename std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::value_type
    >::value
  >::type
>: std::true_type {};

namespace aux {
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;
  template<class T>
  auto adl_begin(T&& v) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<T>(v))); // no implementation
  template<class T>
  auto adl_end(T&& v) -> decltype(end(std::forward<T>(v))); // no implementation
}

template<typename T, typename Container, typename=void>
struct is_container_of_type: std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename Container>
struct is_container_of_type<
  T,
  Container,
  typename std::enable_if<
    // we only want this to be used if we iterable over doubles:
    is_iterator_of_type<
      T,
      decltype(void(aux::adl_begin(*(Container*)nullptr)), aux::adl_end(*(Container*)nullptr)) // ensure being and end work as bonus
    >::value
  >::type
>: std::true_type
{};

template<class Ch, class Tr, class Container>
auto operator<<( std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr>& stream, Container const& c ) ->
  typename std::enable_if<
    is_container_of_type<double, Container>::value,
    decltype(stream)
  >::type
{
  stream << "'double' container: [ ";
  for(auto&& e:c)
    stream << e << " ";
  return stream << "]";
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::vector<double>{1,2,3} << "\n";
  std::cout << std::set<double>{3.14,2.7,-10} << "\n";
  double array[] = {2.5, 3.14, 5.0};
  std::cout << array << "\n";
}
```

With this, not only do arrays of `double`s count as containers over `double`, so does anything where in its namespace you define a `begin` and `end` function that returns iterators over double that takes the container as an argument also works.  This matches how `for(auto&& i:container)` lookup works (perfectly?  reasonably well?), so is a good working definition of "container".

Note, however, that as we add more of these embellishments, fewer current compilers have all of the C++11 features we are using.  The above compiles in gcc 4.6 I believe, but not gcc 4.5.*.

...

And here is the original short code with some testing framework around it: (useful if your compiler throws it up, you can see where it goes wrong below)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template<typename T, typename Iterator, typename=void>
struct is_iterator_of_type: std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename Iterator>
struct is_iterator_of_type<
  T,
  Iterator,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      T,
      typename std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::value_type
    >::value
  >::type
>: std::true_type {};

void test1() {
  std::cout << is_iterator_of_type<int, std::vector<int>::iterator>::value << "\n";
}
template<typename T, typename Container>
auto foo(Container const&) -> typename std::enable_if< is_iterator_of_type<T, typename Container::iterator>::value >::type
{
  std::cout << "Container of int\n";
}
template<typename T>
void foo(...)
{
  std::cout << "No match\n";
}
void test2() {
  std::vector<int> test;
  foo<int>(test);
  foo<int>(test.begin());
  foo<int>(std::set<int>());
}
template<typename Container>
auto operator<<( std::ostream& stream, Container const& c ) ->
  typename std::enable_if< is_iterator_of_type<int, typename Container::iterator>::value, std::ostream& >::type
{
  return stream << "int container\n";
}
void test3() {
  std::vector<int> test;
  std::cout << test;
  std::set<int> bar;
  std::cout << bar;
}
template<typename Container>
auto operator<<( std::ostream& stream, Container const& c ) ->
  typename std::enable_if< is_iterator_of_type<double, typename Container::iterator>::value, std::ostream& >::type
{
  return stream << "double container\n";
}
void test4() {
  std::vector<int> test;
  std::cout << test;
  std::set<int> bar;
  std::cout << bar;
  std::vector<double> dtest;
  std::cout << dtest;
}
void test5() {
  std::vector<bool> test;
  // does not compile (naturally):
  // std::cout << test;
}
template<typename Container>
auto operator<<( std::ostream& stream, Container const& c ) ->
  typename std::enable_if< is_iterator_of_type<bool, typename Container::iterator>::value, std::ostream& >::type
{
  return stream << "bool container\n";
}
void test6() {
  std::vector<bool> test;
  // now compiles:
  std::cout << test;
}
int main() {
  test1();
  test2();
  test3();
  test4();
  test5();
  test6();
}
```

about half of the above is testing boilerplate.  The `is_iterator_of_type` template, and the `operator<<` overloads are what you want.

I am presuming that a container of type `T` is any class with a typedef `iterator` which whose `value_type` is a `T`.  This will cover every `std` container, and most custom ones.

Link to execution run: http://ideone.com/lMUF4i -- note that some compilers don't support full C++11 SFINAE, and may require tomfoolery to get it to work.

Test cases left in to help someone check what level of support their compiler has for these techniques.

Comment: The streaming code is already written.  I'm looking for a way to declare it for all container types.  This solution doesn't work, but if you do have a "correct' method, I'm curious to see it.

Comment: Just use `sizeof(c.begin()==c.end())`, which is shorter and additionally checks that the return types are comparable. Or in C++11 `sizeof(std::begin(c)==std::end(c))`

Comment: @DrewDormann, the above code compiles and runs on ideone.com on a C++11 compiler.  And generates [123].  And if you pass a class without a `begin` or `end` method, the `operator<<` will not match.  Maybe your problem is that your compiler doesn't have `enable_if` yet?  Writing that isn't hard either. @MSalters -- good thought, that does move it a step closer to being correct.

Comment: @DrewDormann or maybe you didn't spot the magic above.  The above code is using SFINAE to make the `operator<<` only match if and only if the passed in type has a `.begin()` and `.end()` method.  If it lacks such methods, the `operator<<` above will fail to match.  I would like to know what you mean by "this solution doesn't work" -- doesn't work *how*?

Comment: @Yakk Ah, since you mentioned "first stab" and compared it to "correct", I figured you saw why this wouldn't work for non-trivial cases.  Your `enable_if` declares this one function to be the correct choice for all containers of anything.  Making one of these for containers of `A` and another for containers of `B` and it won't compile.  It could also cause ambiguity errors against different functions.

Comment: Oh, you want `is_same`, as in `->
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same< typename Container::value_type, X >::value && sizeof(c.begin() == c.end()), std::ostream &>::type` replacing that `enable_if` clause.  The part that is incomplete is that full-on industrial "is this a container" detection is better than `sizeof(c.begin() == c.end())`, but in practice `sizeof(c.begin() == c.end())` is pretty close to "is this a container" and I'm slack.  Detecting "given that it is a container, is it a container of `X`" is trivial.

Comment: Detecting that would indeed answer this question.  :)  Since the bounty is posted, maybe someone will take a stab at it based on what you started.  I would feel bad attempting it and posting the answer to my own bounty.

Comment: @Yakk that's some impressive SFINAE work.  If I used your solution, the function would get called for any type `Container` **iff** `std::iterator_traits< typename Container::Iterator >::value_type` was `X`.  Do I have that right?

Comment: Yes.  There is no official standard for what a `Container` is, so I made one up.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617203/is-it-possible-to-use-type-traits-to-check-whether-a-type-is-a-container and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042824/how-to-write-a-type-trait-is-container-or-is-vector for further discussion on the issue.  The above code doesn't treat an array of X as a container of X, and it could in theory treat something with a typedef `iterator` as a container of X and then fail to compile.  However, it should be good enough to use in most contexts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20954/discussion-between-drew-dormann-and-yakk)

Answer (score 3):

```
template<template<class T, class A> class container>
std::ostream& opertaor << ( std::ostream&, const container<X, std::allocator<X> > &)
{
}
```

This won't work if on your implementation vector, list, etc. have more than 2 template parameters.

Comment: That works for `vector`, `deque` and `list`, but fails for everything else.

Comment: The assumption is that any type with two template parameters `X, std::allocator<X>` would be a container for `X`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple if not elegant - and the next person to maintain your code might appreciate a lack of fancy templates! In practice I would hide the 'Print' method in a cpp, or at least a `Detail` namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <multiset>

class X {};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os, const T& container)
{
    for(auto ii = container.cbegin(); ii != container.cend(); ++ii);
        //etc
        //
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<X>& v) { return Print(os, v); }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::deque<X>& v) { return Print(os, v); }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::list<X>& v) { return Print(os, v); }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<X>& v) { return Print(os, v); }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::multiset<X>& v) { return Print(os, v); }

int main()
{
            // Example
    std::vector<X> v;
    std::cout << v;
}
```

Comment: That is both simple and elegant.  Is there a way to apply this to containers that aren't in the C++03 library?  Or even ones I don't yet know of?

Comment: Just add more overloads. eg `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyContainerType<X>& v);`. You'll know when you need to add an overload because you'll get a compiler error. Another nice thing is the overload can be located with the container - eg, say you deploy your code, and the Print function and your overloads are 'locked down'. If someone creates/uses a new container they can just define the `operator<<` overload with the container - it can use the `Print` function - so they don't need to edit your code to use a new container type.

Comment: I think those are fairly solid solutions, though they don't answer this question.  I agree that if I gave up on making it work for arbitrary containers of `X` or if I gave up on implementing "`operator <<`" this would be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you slightly redefine the question to providing special streaming behavior for any class that provides range based access to Widget, instead of special behavior for all Widget containers, one solution is:

```
  template <class Container>
  std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Container &container) 
  {
    for(const Widget& c : container) {
      out << c;
      out.put(' ');
    }
    return out;
  }
```

This works for `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::deque`, and `std::set`.  If you attempt to stream something that does not provide  range access to Widget, say `std::list<int>`, you'll get a compilation error, because the const Widget reference cannot bind to the ints in `std::list<int>`.  If you provide an overload for operator << for `std::list<int>` the code will compile.

Comment: Replace `Container` with `const Container&` in the signature and this looks like the obvious solution...

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable redefinition of the question.  I think it would cause more errors than you mention though, since that function would be considered when inserting absolutely anything to an `ostream`.  You couldn't have two of them in a project, for example.

Comment: The const & is a good idea, and I edited the code to match.  Drew is right that you couldn't have more than two of them in a project.

Answer (score -1):

While @razeh has a nice solution, if you need to get fancy and have specialized printing for a container of `X` versus a container of `Y`, you can do the following:

```
    // Types for which you want specialized streaming of containers
    // We need some identifiable typedef in these types
    struct  X { typedef void X_type; };
    struct  Y { typedef void Y_type; };


    // Wrappers for implementing streaming logic for each type        

template <typename C>
struct WrapX
{
    WrapX(const C& c) : c(c) { }
    const C& c;

    std::ostream& stream(std::ostream& os)
    {
         // Special container of X printing
         return os;
    }
};

template <typename C>
struct WrapY
{
    WrapY(const C& c) : c(c) { }
    const C& c;

    std::ostream& stream(std::ostream& os)
    {
        // Special container of Y printing
        return os;
    }
};

    // Wrap functions, by using a 'dummy' parameter
    // we can get the compiler to select the function based
    // on the incoming type

template <typename C >
WrapX<C> Wrap(const C& c,  typename C::value_type::X_type* = 0) { return WrapX<C>(c); }

template <typename C>
WrapY<C> Wrap(const C& c, typename C::value_type::Y_type* = 0) { return WrapY<C>(c); }



    // Overload - same problem as @razeh solution, this is a VERY generic
    // function and may clash with other declarations. Keep it closely confined to
    // where you need it.
template <typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) { return Wrap(c).stream(os);  }




int main()
{
    std::vector<X> vx;
    std::cout << vx;

        std::vector<Y> vy;
        std::cout << vy;
}
```