# type_traits for std Container?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits, static-assert

I looked through the listing of `std::type_traits` but I didn't see anything in there pertaining to an `std` container.

I'm looking to validate that a `std` container was passed into a template type at compile time.

```
template < typename T >
void foo( T bar )
{
    static_assert( is_std_container??? );
}
```

Comment: no such thing exists, and I dont think it makes any sense. what might make sense would be if it fulfills the concept of a certain type of container, but I would think that needs to wait until concepts (light)

Comment: If you only need to support a fixed set of container types, you can just write your own traits class.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12042824 duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7617203 duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9407367 Thanks for searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not exist.

You can create your own trait if you know the set of container types that should be supported :

```
template<class T>
struct is_container
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<>
template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_container<std::vector<T, Alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true; 
};

// ... same specializations for other containers.
```

And you use it like other traits:

```
cout << is_container<std::vector<int>>::value << endl;
cout << is_container<int>::value << endl;
```

See it [here](http://ideone.com/W5GjUl).

Note that usually you should pass iterators to your functions, not containers. So you keep your code container-independent and much more generic.

Answer (score 5):

As already other guys answered in the comments there's no standard way of doing this. However, you could define your own trait system to determine whether a type is `std` container or not like in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct container_traits {
  static bool const value = false;  
};

template <typename... Args>
struct container_traits<std::vector<Args...>> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct container_traits<std::deque<Args...>> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct container_traits<std::list<Args...>> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct container_traits<std::set<Args...>> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct container_traits<std::map<Args...>> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct container_traits<std::unordered_set<Args...>> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct container_traits<std::unordered_map<Args...>> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_std {
    static constexpr bool const value = container_traits<T>::value;
};

auto main() -> int {
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(v)>::value << std::endl;
  std::deque<int> dq;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(dq)>::value << std::endl;
  std::set<int> s;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(s)>::value << std::endl;
  std::map<int, int> m;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(m)>::value << std::endl;
  std::unordered_set<int> us;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(us)>::value << std::endl;
  std::unordered_map<int, int> um;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(um)>::value << std::endl;
  std::list<int> l;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(l)>::value << std::endl;
  int i;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(i)>::value << std::endl;
  double d;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_std<decltype(d)>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/322e1c2f8cdc642c)

Comment: This is good use of variadic templates to avoid stating the extra constructor parameters for all the containers. std::boolalpha only needs be sent to std::cout once; not every time.